# how compilers evaluate mathematical expressions?

Tags: evaluation, infix-notation

i know that it has to do something with compilers converting the **infix** expressions to **postfix** or **prefix** (i don't know which one exactly) and i think compilers do that because in postfix and prefix expressions parenthesis are not needed to emphasize on  the precedence of an operator.
so can anyone tell me why and how exactly computer evaluate mathematical expressions?
is the process the same for all the programming languages compilers?

Comment: The problem here is that there methods are in some sense uniform, but individual implementation vary rather a lot. Take a compilers course or even just read Crenshaw's *Let's Build a Compiler* and you'll get the broad picture.

Comment: @dmckee thanks. off-topic question: is there a "question-and-answer" Web sites  like stack overflow  that i can ask questions pertaining computer science but like : what is ajax or what is a good book for learning c++ and such questions . because i think these kinds of questions are not appreciate here.

Answer (score 1):

Usually it's to postfix notation, using operand and operator stacks. Any first year computer science book (compiler design) will discuss the details. It has to do with parentheses encountered, and relative precedence (and associativity) of operators encountered in the input. Most computer languages have similar evaluation, precedence, and associativity rules, and will use a similar process. But not all!